# Programs running aapt in android sdk from shell and from sbt

Tags: android, scala, aapt

I have a weird problem where I cannot run aapt from an sbt command as well as from the shell.

I run this command:

**sbt update package-debug**

And everything hums along until I get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/egervari/Programs/android-sdk-linux_x86/platforms/android-7/tools/aapt": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

So I try running it manually, just for the heck of it:

```
egervari@ken:~/Programs/android-sdk-linux_x86/platforms/android-7/tools$ ./aapt
bash: ./aapt: No such file or directory
```

This is pretty weird because it's right there:

```
egervari@ken:~/Programs/android-sdk-linux_x86/platforms/android-7/tools$ ls -la
total 4660
drwxr-xr-x 3 egervari egervari    4096 2010-10-16 09:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 egervari egervari    4096 2010-10-16 09:13 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 egervari egervari 3472673 2010-10-16 09:13 aapt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 egervari egervari 1050328 2010-10-16 09:13 aidl
-rwxrwxrwx 1 egervari egervari  213690 2010-10-16 09:13 dexdump
-rwxrwxrwx 1 egervari egervari    2497 2010-10-16 09:13 dx
drwxr-xr-x 2 egervari egervari    4096 2010-10-16 09:13 lib
-rw-r--r-- 1 egervari egervari   10800 2010-10-16 09:13 NOTICE.txt
egervari@ken:~/Programs/android-sdk-linux_x86/platforms/android-7/tools$
```

Help? :/

Comment: Obvious question perhaps, but has it *ever* run?

Comment: No, this is brand new install of the android sdk on a brand new installation of ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to run a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit OS. Maybe you're missing the required shared libraries. Try running `file aapt` and `ldd ./aapt` to see what it says.

If this is the case [then installing ia32-libs could fix it](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html#troubleshooting), as there are no 64-bit binaries available.

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: Oh, this could be the case... I'll try those and let you know. I am running 64bit. If you're right, I hope google has x64 versions of these...

Comment: Yeah, both reported 32-bit libraries: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, not stripped.

Comment: The problem is that I already had ia32-libs installed. It says "ia32-libs is already the newest version.
ia32-libs set to manually installed." But when I run it, it works now anyway. VERY WEIRD INDEED! Thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

ia32-libs is deprecated.

The following worked for me:

> apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0

I was still getting error when running aapt, so I installed this:

> apt-get install lib32stdc++6

works perfect now.