# Error: Cannot run aapt

Tags: android, linux, adt, aapt

When I compile an android application ( I tried with the sample ones from the sdk). I get this error:

```
>Error executing aapt: Cannot run program "/home/roel/projects/sdk/build-tools/18.0.1/aapt": >error=2, No such file or directory: error=2, No such file or directory    KeyChainDemo        >line 1 Android ADT Problem
```

But aapt is at that location?

```
>[roel@archUSB 18.0.1]$ ls /home/roel/projects/sdk/build-tools/18.0.1/

>NOTICE.txt  aidl     dx   libLLVM.so  libbcinfo.so  llvm-rs-cc    source.properties
>**aapt**        dexdump  lib  libbcc.so   libclang.so   renderscript
```

Note: I also get the error "R cannot be resolved", but I'm pretty sure that when I solve problem 1, I also solve this problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android SDK on a 64-bit linux machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710499/android-sdk-on-a-64-bit-linux-machine)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS solution:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib lib32z1 lib32stdc++6
```

Reason:
aapt needs 32-bit libraries installed

Comment: Unable to locate package

Comment: Just comment the reason, aapt need 32 bit libs installed

Comment: Even a better solution than the [Google proposed one](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools)

Comment: What a horribly useless error message! Shame on the dev(s) who wrote that!

Answer (score 21):

The problem was my 64bit OS , I missed some 32 bit libs ;)

Comment: I'm having the same issue... on Ubuntu 13.04 64bits. What libs did you install?

Comment: @h_rules: `apt-get install ia32-libs` as instructed at http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html (see "Troubleshooting Ubuntu")

Comment: ubuntu 12.04 64bit , was working on Android studio , got it done for me too

Comment: Thank you that worked. Following is the solution for Debian 7.

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 ia32-libs is deprecated so I had to install lib32z1 and lib32stdc++6

Comment: Why is your sudden discovery marked as an answer? :D

Comment: I think the answer by Benjamin deserves to be marked as the accepted answer.  Can you please accept that.

Answer (score 20):

SDK tools 24 has a bug, build will fail with the same error. Should be fixed in the new version, for now the workaround in tools/ant/build.xml place

```
<property name="aapt" location="${sdk.dir}/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt" />
<property name="aidl" location="${sdk.dir}/build-tools/22.0.1/aidl" />
<property name="dx" location="${sdk.dir}/build-tools/22.0.1/dx" />
<property name="zipalign" location="${sdk.dir}/build-tools/22.0.1/zipalign" />
```

at the end of the xml in the root tag. Replace 22.0.1 with your build tools version

Comment: Life saviour is here guys

Comment: You really helped me.

Comment: Or can just specify **executable=** in his build.xml without the **dir=** statement.

Answer (score 7):

Debian 7 Wheezy solution:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu 13.10 solution:

Append

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse
```

to **/etc/apt/sources.list.**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem today. If anyone from the future is having this problem, try the solution here

[Programs running aapt in android sdk from shell and from sbt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949206/programs-running-aapt-in-android-sdk-from-shell-and-from-sbt#3949626)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today, [this](http://www.ossmentor.com/2013/08/error-executing-aapt-within-eclipse.html) helped me.

Arch Linux 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

aapt is a 32 bit application and will fail on a 64 bit box until 32 bits are enabled and libs added

This is current solution as of Ubuntu 16.04 / 17.10

```
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures  #  if below was never run this returns nothing ... afterwards it will return : i386
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get -qqy update
sudo apt-get -qqy install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
```