# How to solve "Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool" when installing Android Studio on Fedora 21?

Tags: android, android-studio, fedora-21

I'm trying to install Android Studio on a 64-bit Fedora 21 system.

I got the JRE and JDK pre-requisites installed, unpacked the Android Studio installation, and from its "bin" directory issued "sh studio.sh" to complete the installation.

The Setup Wizard failed with message "Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool" and suggested that 32-bit libraries might be needed.

Comment: This bug is known upstream as [82711](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82711) There's a similar question for Ubuntu/Debian [Unable to install Android Studio in Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28847151/1260896).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool in ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241640/error-unable-to-run-mksdcard-sdk-tool-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From a discussion of the problem at http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=303238 I installed several packages with the command

```
sudo yum install compat-libstdc++-296.i686 compat-libstdc++-33.i686 ncurses-libs.i686 compat-libstdc++-33.x86_64
```

After these (and their dependencies) were successfully installed, clicking "RETRY" in the Setup Wizard popup displaying the error allowed the installation of Android Studio to proceed to a successful completion.

Comment: Bug [82711](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82711) has some more information.

Comment: this also worked with my CentOS7 (without compat-libstdc++-296.i686).

Comment: Thanks @DenysVitali, unfortunately this did not work for me. I had to turn on multilib support first. This is due to the three lib32 library dependencies, which are: lib32-fontconfig, lib32-libxrender and lib32-mesa. If you are running a 32 bit arch system, these will be called fontconfig, libxrender and mesa

Comment: Same problem. Worked on Fedora 25 as well.

Answer (score 59):

(*This answer is for an Ubuntu distribution*)

If you are running the **64-bit Ubuntu**, the following fix should solve your problem:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
```

---

### UPDATE:

For Ubuntu 15.10 and 16 (*Provided by [tony gil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1166727/tony-gil) and [briankip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/536434/briankip)*) :

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6
```

This also works on GNU/Linux Debian 9 (Stretch) x86_64.

Comment: Okay, but there are several answers already for questions which reference this problem on Ubuntu, and this question specified Fedora. Since the solutions are not the same on the two operating systems, I'm not sure your answer clarifies more than it confuses.

Comment: This question is about Fedora. for Debian/Ubuntu, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/28847151/1260896

Comment: on ubuntu 15.10 i had to change this to `sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6`

Comment: On Ubuntu 16 I removed  lib32bz2-1.0 since it seems it's not available in the repositories, so `sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5  lib32stdc++6
`

Comment: Using this command i had issue.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package lib32bz2-1.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'lib32bz2-1.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lib32bz2-1.0'

Comment: @mcduffee From comments in this answer we can tell that Ubuntu has much more users than Fedora...

Comment: @Franklin Yu: I suppose. I haven't used Fedora for a couple of years, and am mostly on Ubuntu myself these days. I guess, with the passage of time, I'm glad the hordes of Ubuntu folks who couldn't find the hordes of Ubuntu solutions on StackOverflow were at least able to get the help they so desperately needed.

Answer (score 17):

The Fedora Project Wiki also has [an article](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/HOWTO_Setup_Android_Development#Install_Android_SDK) about how to set up Android Development.

For 64-bit systems, you will have to install these packages

> yum install glibc.i686 glibc-devel.i686 libstdc++.i686 zlib-devel.i686 ncurses-devel.i686 libX11-devel.i686 libXrender.i686 libXrandr.i686

For Fedora 22+ on a 64-bit system, you need to use dnf to install these packages

> dnf install glibc.i686 glibc-devel.i686 libstdc++.i686 zlib-devel.i686 ncurses-devel.i686 libX11-devel.i686 libXrender.i686 libXrandr.i686

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks a lot .

Comment: You don't actually needs those `-devel` packages. `glibc.i686 libstdc++.i686 zlib.i686 ncurses.i686 libX11.i686 libXrender.i686 libXrandr.i686` suffice, and are much smaller. Anyway the wiki link is great.

Answer (score 4):

Other answers here doesn't seem to work for the Fedora. So here I came up with a tested solution for this :

```
sudo dnf install compat-libstdc++-296 compat-libstdc++-33 glibc libgcc nss-softokn-freebl libstdc++ ncurses-libs zlib-devel.i686 ncurses-devel.i686 ant
```

Answer (score 1):

Even i got the same error while installing Android sdk in ubuntu 14.04. 
This is a compatibility issue where you're trying to install Android SDK in a 64 bit system which inturn requires some 32 bit binaries for completing the installation.

> Here is the steps to resolve the issue.

1. Open the a new terminal (ctrl + alt +t or R-click and new terminal)
2. paste the command 
   " sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6 " and if action requires password, give it.

Thats it. All the required 32bit binaries will get installed. once it gets installed, you can restart the installation of Android SDK, which will get installed completely.

> Find the Tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71OUBuwwFvM)!

Answer (score 0):

on Fedora 24 login with su

```
dnf install compat-libstdc++-296 compat-libstdc++-33 glibc libgcc nss-softokn-freebl libstdc++ ncurses-libs zlib-devel.i686 ncurses-devel.i686 ant
```

Comment: It's hard to tell at a glance how this is different from existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer on this official documentation
https://developer.android.com/studio/troubleshoot.html#linux-libraries

Shortly i put the snippets here

## Linux libraries

If you are running **Android Studio on a 64-bit Linux machine**, you may need to install some specific libraries, as follows.

If you are running a **64-bit version of Ubuntu**, you need to install some 32-bit libraries with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 lib32bz2-1.0
```

If you are running **64-bit Fedora**, the command is:

```
sudo yum install zlib.i686 ncurses-libs.i686 bzip2-libs.i686
```

*Please note that those instructions can be obsolete someday, so it is better to follow / [visit the official site](https://developer.android.com/studio/troubleshoot.html#linux-libraries) to prevent unresolved problems*