# unable to run mksdcard tool during android studio installation on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio

I see that i have to run this in terminal:

```
   sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
```

but I got this:

```
   E: Unable to locate package lib32bz2-1.0
   E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lib32bz2-1.0'
```

please assist how this can be fixed?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847151/unable-to-install-android-studio-in-ubuntu/30067060#30067060

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool in ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241640/error-unable-to-run-mksdcard-sdk-tool-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 4):

I removed lib32bz2-1.0 and installed it successfully.

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6
```

Answer (score 3):

## Are you triying to install Android Studio on Ubuntu?

### Option 1: Ubuntu Snap (new and easiest solution)

#### Software store

Open it and install android studio package.

#### Command line

`sudo snap install android-studio --classic`

[Android Studio snap package](https://snapcraft.io/android-studio)

### Option 2: Oficial documentation tutorial (old solution)

If you say: Yes!!. This answer is for you :-).

Maybe are you triying to install android studio with [this tutorial?](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html?hl=es-419). It has deprecated dependencies on Ubuntu 16.04.

This command has issues:

> sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6

After a few searchs on Google I found a possible solution in this post: [Bad dependency on install command](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=207212).

This command specifies the 32 bits version of the extra libraries that you need to setup android studio. It works for me on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install libz1:i386 libncurses5:i386 libbz2-1.0:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

Hope it helps :-).