# unable to install 32 bit libraries on 64 bit ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu-14.04, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to set up android dev environment on my 64 bit ubuntu 14.04.

But I am getting a dependency deadlock while trying to install 32 bit libraries.

I have added multi-architecture support.
`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

But when I try to install the libraries, I get this

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    libc6:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
>    libstdc++6:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I have tried to install libgcc along with this too, but that leads to just an infinite loop of other dependencies.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/359156/how-do-you-run-a-32-bit-program-on-a-64-bit-version-of-ubuntu

Comment: Nope, its not a duplicate. The answer in that question says ia32-libs are no longer required. That does not work for me. When I try to run the android emulator, it errors out saying no 32 bit libraries are available.

Comment: Has this been set ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true? 32 bit binaries for the emulator are deprecated, you shouldn't be running into this matter. Make sure you have downloaded the latest version.

Comment: Nope, that is not set. However, I think I need the 32bit libraries. Otherwise, the mksdcard is failing like discussed in these - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241640/unable-to-run-mksdcard-sdk-tool-ubuntu and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847151/unable-to-install-android-studio-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like my system libraries were screwed up when I upgraded Ubuntu using the system upgrader. Finally I needed to reinstall my root partition and I am up and running !

Lesson - Do no upgrade your release unless you want to go into weird dependency issues.