# Installing Android Studio in Ubuntu: Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, android-studio, ubuntu-14.04

I am working on setup Android Studio in Ubuntu, I tried install the packages that google mentioned for 64Bit OS

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
```

but still not working and show this error:
[image]

here is the terminal Log :

```
~/AndroidStudio/bin$ sh ./studio.sh
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
[   2252]   WARN - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Native file watcher is not executable: <a href="/home/ahmed/AndroidStudio/bin/fsnotifier64">/home/ahmed/AndroidStudio/bin/fsnotifier64</a> 
[   7618]   WARN - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Couldn't find existing SDK 
[  72252]  ERROR - ard.ConsolidatedProgressStep$1 - Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool. 
com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.WizardException: Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool.
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.CheckSdkOperation.perform(CheckSdkOperation.java:128)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.CheckSdkOperation.perform(CheckSdkOperation.java:40)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallOperation.execute(InstallOperation.java:68)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallOperation$OperationChain.perform(InstallOperation.java:151)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallOperation.execute(InstallOperation.java:68)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallOperation$OperationChain.perform(InstallOperation.java:149)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallOperation.execute(InstallOperation.java:68)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallOperation$OperationChain.perform(InstallOperation.java:149)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallOperation.execute(InstallOperation.java:68)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallOperation$OperationChain.perform(InstallOperation.java:149)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallOperation.execute(InstallOperation.java:68)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.InstallComponentsPath.runLongOperation(InstallComponentsPath.java:297)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.ConsolidatedProgressStep.doLongRunningOperation(ConsolidatedProgressStep.java:78)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.ConsolidatedProgressStep.access$000(ConsolidatedProgressStep.java:32)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.ConsolidatedProgressStep$1.run(ConsolidatedProgressStep.java:58)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.FirstRunWizardHost$LongRunningOperationWrapper.run(FirstRunWizardHost.java:434)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:400)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
[  72254]  ERROR - ard.ConsolidatedProgressStep$1 - Android Studio 1.5.1  Build #AI-141.2456560 
[  72255]  ERROR - ard.ConsolidatedProgressStep$1 - JDK: 1.8.0_72 
[  72255]  ERROR - ard.ConsolidatedProgressStep$1 - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
[  72255]  ERROR - ard.ConsolidatedProgressStep$1 - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
[  72255]  ERROR - ard.ConsolidatedProgressStep$1 - OS: Linux 
[  72255]  ERROR - ard.ConsolidatedProgressStep$1 - Last Action:
```

How to solve it? thank you!

Comment: Try running `mksdcard` from the command line and see what errors you get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool in ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241640/error-unable-to-run-mksdcard-sdk-tool-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

Just use

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

This got mine sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried installing this packages?

sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6

Source: [Unable to install Android Studio in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847151/unable-to-install-android-studio-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

The Android Developer site has the documentation for installing Android Studio on Linux and it covers this issue:
https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html

Quoting from link:

Required libraries for 64-bit machines:

If you are running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, you need to install some 32-bit libraries with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386
```

If you are running 64-bit Fedora, the command is:

```
sudo yum install zlib.i686 ncurses-libs.i686 bzip2-libs.i686
```

As an aside - the other thing you'll need is java. Since Android N was switched to OpenJDK I see no reason to stick with Oracle when developing Android applications.
https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2016/01/android-n-switches-to-openjdk-google-tells-oracle-it-is-protected-by-the-gpl/

So, to get OpenJDK just follow the OpenJDK documentation:
http://openjdk.java.net/install/

For Ubuntu this works just fine:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```