# unable to run mksdcard sdk tool ubuntu 16.04 64bit

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu-16.04

I downloded android studio and I tried to install on ubuntu 16.04 64 bit but it has `"unable to run mksdcard sdk tool"` error.

I checked all solutions but they produce errors too.

[image: apt-get command log]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool in ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241640/error-unable-to-run-mksdcard-sdk-tool-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that the only package you need is `lib32stdc++6` for **ubuntu 16.04**

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled upon this issue myself.
I guess that you found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847151/unable-to-install-android-studio-in-ubuntu) from 2015?

Well, the given solution is a bit outdated but still pertinent: the 64bit Ubuntu 16.04 is indeed missing the 32bits version of the libraries and the
**lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6** libraries advised to be installed seems to have been removed from the official repos.

However You can still get them with using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libz1:i386 libncurses5:i386 libbz2-1.0:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

Then the installer should work just fine
Hope it will be of any help.

Comment: I installed all package that you said but it does not work and it has error [link](https://i.imgsafe.org/9f979d2db9.png)

Comment: Have you tried the actual command line that I gave you?
And is the error still the same?

Answer (score 1):

take a look at https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html

Select Linux...

**Required libraries for 64-bit machines:**
**If you are running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, you need to install some 32-bit libraries with the following command:**

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386
```

**If you are running 64-bit Fedora, the command is:**

```
sudo yum install zlib.i686 ncurses-libs.i686 bzip2-libs.i686
```

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 18.04 and above versions, the following will work

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 libgcc1:i386 zlib1g:i386 libncurses5:i386
```

## Ubuntu18.04