# Can not run android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, ubuntu-15.04

Recently installed Android Studio 1.0.1 (old version for some reasons) on Ubuntu 15, and I am trying to create a new project. Whenever I build it I get this error

> Cannot run program "/home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt": error=2 No such file or directory"

The file exists there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Cannot run aapt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041769/error-cannot-run-aapt)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
```

Comment: Works great but would you please provide an explanation?

Comment: It works. In case others wonder: it doesn't work with lib64stdc++6:i386 and lib64z1:i386 instead.

Comment: Please note, with android build tools >= 24.0.0, this is no longer required

Comment: @Nonos and Saeed Darvish: it works because your Ubuntu must be 64-bit and aapt needs 32-bit libraries to run, so it needs some 32-bit libraries installed.

Comment: Just run `file build-tools/23.0.3/aapt` and the result is `ELF 32-bit LSB shared object`, that is, a 32-bit executable.

Comment: Also works for docker images of JDK, that are 32 bits images. this is cases for CI/CD servers and services like Buddy Works

Answer (score 0):

please check your **compileSdkVersion** and **buildToolsVersion** and **targetSdkVersion** please same the value. simple :

compileSdkVersion "23"
buildToolsVersion "23"
targetSdkVersion "23"

Comment: I used the wizard to create the project. How can i make sure that everything has the same version ?

Comment: in **build.gradle** or tap ctrl + shift + alt + S for change value 3 attrib on above

Answer (score 0):

I am using react-native for android. I encountered the same problem

```
Cannot run program "/home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt": 
error=2 No such file or directory"
```

but I changed the build tool version to 26.0.2 and it solved build completed without any problem.
I barely know why it happened.