# Read and write multiple commands on command prompt through java program

Tags: java, cmd, ubuntu-14.04, command-line-arguments

I am trying to sign apk by using apksigner and zipalign tools, which are located in jdk/bin folder. I have already set path environment variable to it. Now what I want to do is, execute some shell commands which signs my apk through java code in ubuntu. Commands are,

**command-1 :**

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore /Desktop/my-release-key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias app
```

This command required some inputs at run time, like first name last name etc.

**command-2 :**

```
./zipalign -v 4 inputAPK.apk outputAPK.apk
```

**command-3 :**

```
apksigner sign --min-sdk-version 15 --ks my-release-key.jks outputAPK.apk
```

**command-4 :**

`apksigner verify --min-sdk-version 15 outputAPK.apk`

All above 4 commands I want to execute it through java code in ubuntu environment, how can I achieve it?

Comment: Whats the problem that you're facing?

Comment: Actually I am new to java programming, so don't know the exact solution for it, I mean how can I execute above 4 commands through java program and also at runtime how can I send inputs to the command line in ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run cmd commands through java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464111/run-cmd-commands-through-java)

Comment: I tried with the link you suggested but while running second command getting exception like, java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "zipalign -v 4 myInput.apk myOutput.apk": error=2, No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh k. You can use `java.lang.Runtime.exec` to run simple code. Have a look at these sites:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)

http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010016

https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/

Also you can use `Process.getOutputStream()` method to get input. Whatever data you enter will be passed to your input stream.

Comment: I tried with the link you suggested but while running second command getting exception like, java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "zipalign -v 4 myInput.apk myOutput.apk": error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: In that case either you are pointing to a wrong location as the error says... or you need to do this - `sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib lib32z1 lib32stdc++6`

Comment: zipalign tool is located in Android/sdk/build tools/24.0.3/zipalign. I have already located this path in environment variable, but even though not working.

Comment: How about your OS? x64 or x32.? Also check your build.xml.

Comment: Hey! [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041769/error-cannot-run-aapt) may help you.

Comment: By the way when you find a answer useful do mark it as accepted or vote it so that people with same problem will find it easy to get solutions.