# Error: Eclipse not working with this message in console"Cannot run aapt"

Tags: android, eclipse, aapt

When i open my eclipse it shows this error in my Console.

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Error executing aapt: Cannot run program "/home/amar/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt": error=13, Permission denied: error=13, Permission denied   DevsmartAndroid     line 1  Android ADT Problem

Please help me out.

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041769/error-cannot-run-aapt

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949206/programs-running-aapt-in-android-sdk-from-shell-and-from-sbt#3949626

Comment: @SmartphoneDeveloper i have added these too in build but again getting the same error

Comment: It might be the issue that your machine is 32 bit & from developer site you might downloaded 64 bit Eclipse or vise versa.

Comment: @SmartphoneDeveloper /home/amar/Downloads/eclipse-standard-luna-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz this is my eclipse version

Comment: very basic but you tried to restart your PC ?

Comment: @SmartphoneDeveloper I am using Ubuntu OS type is 64-bit. i am working here on same PC from last 6 months but it's hanging so Ubuntu is again installed that's it.

Comment: than this is not my case as em not familiar with Ubuntu :)